# How do I extract a fractional unicode from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I get a string from the server which looks similar to this:

- 2 ½ cups 'cauliflower rice'
- Juice of 1 ⅔ lemon
- 2 1/2 tbsp of butter

I need to extract the fractional portion which can or cannot be a unicode. Please note that the fraction can be - any number/any number.

I tried the following regex and none of them worked well with the unicode:

- `/(\d+(\s|⁄|[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]))\d*/`
- `/(\d+(\s*[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E])?\/\d+)/`
- `/(\d+(\s+|⁄|[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]|(?:\d+\s*\/\s*\d+))\d*)/`
- `/(\d+(?:\s*(?:\d+\/\d+|⁄|[\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]))?)/`
- `/(?<!\d)(?:\d+\s*)?[⁄\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]/`

My sample code:

```
const fractionRegex = /(\d\s)?[⁄\u00BC-\u00BE\u2150-\u215E]/; // Regex to find a fraction
const fractionMatch = ingredient.match(fractionRegex)?.[0] ?? '';
console.log('fractionMatch', fractionMatch);
```

Comment: How about `\d*\s*[¼-⅞]`?

Comment: What about [`\d+[/⁄]\d+|[¼-¾⅐-⅞]`](https://regex101.com/r/nhWrjR/1) ?

Comment: All the Unicode 15 names claiming to be fractions: `[¼-¾୲-୷౸-౾൘-൞൳-൸⁄⅐-⅟↉⳽꠰-꠵------]` or as utf32 code points : `[\u00bc-\u00be\u0b72-\u0b77\u0c78-\u0c7e\u0d58-\u0d5e\u0d73-\u0d78\u2044\u2150-\u215f\u2189\u2cfd\ua830-\ua835\U000109bc-\U000109bd\U000109f6-\U000109ff\U00010a48\U00010e7b-\U00010e7e\U00010f26\U00011fc0-\U00011fd4\U0001ecad-\U0001ecaf\U0001ed3c-\U0001ed3d]`

Answer (score 3):

Try normalizing the string first, replace the "FRACTION SLASH" symbol with the normal slash and extract:

```js
text = `
2 ½ cups 'cauliflower rice'
Juice of 1 ⅔ lemon
2 1/2 tbsp of butter
`

console.log(
    text.normalize('NFKD')
    .replaceAll('\u2044', '/')
    .match(/\d\/\d/g)
    )
```

For your reference, here's a complete list of unicode "vulgar fractions":

```
¼    00BC;VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER
½    00BD;VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF
¾    00BE;VULGAR FRACTION THREE QUARTERS
⅐   2150;VULGAR FRACTION ONE SEVENTH
⅑   2151;VULGAR FRACTION ONE NINTH
⅒   2152;VULGAR FRACTION ONE TENTH
⅓    2153;VULGAR FRACTION ONE THIRD
⅔    2154;VULGAR FRACTION TWO THIRDS
⅕    2155;VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH
⅖    2156;VULGAR FRACTION TWO FIFTHS
⅗    2157;VULGAR FRACTION THREE FIFTHS
⅘    2158;VULGAR FRACTION FOUR FIFTHS
⅙    2159;VULGAR FRACTION ONE SIXTH
⅚    215A;VULGAR FRACTION FIVE SIXTHS
⅛    215B;VULGAR FRACTION ONE EIGHTH
⅜    215C;VULGAR FRACTION THREE EIGHTHS
⅝    215D;VULGAR FRACTION FIVE EIGHTHS
⅞    215E;VULGAR FRACTION SEVEN EIGHTHS
↉   2189;VULGAR FRACTION ZERO THIRDS
```